# jQuery: multiple same name checkbox fields, but using $(this) selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes:

```
<div class="abc">
  <%= check_box_tag "closed" %>
  <%= select_tag :time %>
</div>
<div class="abc">
  <%= check_box_tag "closed" %>
  <%= select_tag :time %>
</div>
<div class="abc">
  <%= check_box_tag "closed" %>
  <%= select_tag :time %>
</div>
<div class="abc">
  <%= check_box_tag "closed" %>
  <%= select_tag :time %>
</div>
```

They have the same name and id `#closed`

How do I do it so when I click on the checkbox (say the last checkbox) it will disable the last select_tag?

I tried something like this:

```
$("#closed", this).change ->
  alert("test")
  $(this).closest(".abc").prop('disabled', true)
```

So far it only works if I click on the first checkbox in the DOM.

Thanks

Comment: can you share the generated html

Comment: __IDs must be unique in HTML.__ they can have same `name`. You can use class instead

Comment: **same name and id #closed** invalid markup generation.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L9ENJ/3/

Answer (score 0):

`.abc` is a `<div>`. Use `.next()` to locate the `<select>`...

```
$("#closed", this).change ->
  $(this).next("select").prop('disabled', true)
```

As others have mentioned, having multiple elements with the same id is invalid HTML. Consider changing it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's not a good practice to use same `id` for multiple items in HTML document. But if you are sure that the `checkbox` and the `select` are always in the same level in the document you can use `siblings` to get the select -

```
$("#closed", this).change ->
  alert("test")
  $(this).siblings(".abc").prop('disabled', true)
```

or may be

```
$("#closed", this).change ->
alert("test")
$(this).parent().find(".abc").prop('disabled', true)
```

Comment: `closest` only works if the item you are looking for is an ancestor in the DOM tree otherwise not.